how to list an Organization or a repo under Top repos?
first image
i wanted to add Glob-Educate in the List under Top Repositories !
second imge
thanks for help !?
tried to star the Glob-Educate and also adding some Repos in it, but still did not work. is there any Option that i can do to list my Repos or Org like the first image ?

Do you have any commits done in that repository?

Thanks alot for responding.
This was exactly the Problem, that i did not make any commits in that Repo !
Problem solved, thanx again
